# Find a date in a range which has been calculated from a formula and is formatted with UK date formatting

Tags: excel, vba, date

I would like to return the cell in which a date resides. There is one incidence of each date in column B, formatted `dd/mm/yyyy`. This is calculated from the cell two above (e.g. using `=B3+7`).

I have managed to retrieve the date using `application.vlookup` so I know it's "there". The immediate window gives the correct date using `? activecell.value`

I cannot get the range.find function to return anything. If I enter a string with a USA date format such as `09/23/2014` into the column then range.find returns a value, but for UK formatted dates (`=23/09/2014`) it returns `Nothing`

Is the range.find function only capable of handling US dates?

```
Sub columnfind()
 Dim DateRow, correctCell As Range
 Set DateRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:B1000")

 Dim strCurrentDate As String
 Dim IntDate As Long
 IntDate = CLng(CDbl(Now()))

 strCurrentDate = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")

 Set correctCell = DateRow.Find(IntDate, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
 Set correctCell = DateRow.Find(strCurrentDate)
 Set correctCell = DateRow.Find(Date)

 cell = Application.VLookup(IntDate - 1, ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B1000"), 1, 1)'verify existence of date for my sanity
End Sub
```

.   .

Comment: It seems so
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Range("A1").Select
Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
Set h = Range("A1:A4").Find("21/03", , , , , , , , True)
MsgBox h.Address
```

You define the format for the date, after use the bool **SearchFormat** option in the Find method.

Comment: Thanks, this is the sort of thing I was looking for, rather than using a workaround. :)

Answer (score 1):

If **Find()** does not work with certain formats, just don't use it:

```
Sub ColumnFind()
    Dim bRng As Range, r As Range
    Set bRng = Range("B1:B1000")
    For Each r In bRng
        If r.Text = "23/9/2014" Then
            MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub ColumnFind()
    Dim bRng As Range, r As Range
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = Format(Date, "dd/m/yyyy")
    Set bRng = Range("B1:B1000")
    For Each r In bRng
        If r.Text = sDate Then
            MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround now, if it is true that `range.find` doesn't work with non-US dates.

```
Sub columnfind()
Dim DateCol, correctCell As Range
Set DateCol = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B1000")

Dim strCurrentDate As String

DateCol.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"

strCurrentDate = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")
DateCol.Find(strCurrentDate).Select
DateCol.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"


End Sub
```